# Can't get HTML using PhantomJS and selenium driver from a debian server

Tags: debian, http, python, selenium, phantomjs

I am developping a python program that uses selenium (webdriver python bindings) and PhantomJS (headless WebKit scriptable with a JavaScript API) to load and interact with websites.

When I use this program on a **local** ubuntu computer/network it loads the websites correctly ; I can dump all their the HTML :

> print webdriver.page_source

When I run it on the **server**, this line only prints

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

It looks like the server answered the request with an **empty** HTML page.

This issue happens on 2 websites, but the program works correctly for the third website.
This makes me think that it is a *networking issue more than a programming issue* (?).
The server is provided by a vps provider.

From the server, I can ping the server of one of the website that answers empty HTML which makes me think that I am **not** ip blacklisted or banned.

Here is netstat -tulpen output (ran on server)
:

> tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41207           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          267296     22458/phantomjs
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:38457           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          267294     22463/phantomjs
>   tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:33667           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          267295     22461/phantomjs

I don't know how to debug this / understand what is happening.

**Update :** After some testing, I made a JS script that directly uses PhantomJS to dump the HTML content of a page and log errors.

It gives

> FAIL to load the address
>   Error creating SSL context (error:140A90C4:SSL routines:func(169):reason(196))

So it could be related to PhantomJS or something that blocks it.

Answer (score 0):

After determining that the bug seems to come from PhantomJS, I played with its options and parameters.

It seems like the version I ran on the server (1.9.8) is broken for some of the websites I need to interact with.

I installed 2.1.1 (the version that I ran on client) on the server, and it now works well.